# How to map a nested json object to a POCO with multiple custom classes using AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, mapping, automapper

I tried several answered questions related to my problem but I can't seem to resolve the issue.

Here is the JSON object I am sending to my API:

```
{
    "userName": "Test_06",
    "password": "@00a00B00c",
    "firstName": "Test",
    "lastName": "Test",
    "address": {
        "houseNumber": 1,
        "appartementBus": "A bus 34",
        "street": "Teststreet",
        "ZIP": "0000",
        "country": "Test"
    }
}
```

And I am trying to map the address object into the Address POCO:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Kubex.Models
{

  public class Address
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public int HouseNumber { get; set; }
      public string AppartementBus { get; set; }

      public int StreetId { get; set; }
      public virtual Street Street { get; set; }
      public int ZIPId { get; set; }
      public virtual ZIP ZIP { get; set; }
      public int CountryId { get; set; }
      public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
  }
}
```

The following types are basically the same, example of Country looks like

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace Kubex.Models
    {
        public class Country
        {
            public byte Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

The error I am getting back from Postman is the following:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "address.ZIP": [
            "Error converting value \"0000\" to type 'Kubex.Models.ZIP'. Path 'address.ZIP', line 10, position 18."
        ],
        "address.street": [
            "Error converting value \"Teststreet\" to type 'Kubex.Models.Street'. Path 'address.street', line 9, position 27."
        ],
        "address.country": [
            "Error converting value \"Test\" to type 'Kubex.Models.Country'. Path 'address.country', line 11, position 22."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|cca8afa7-463e762ee0ed670d."
}
```

I tried to create mappings for every Type, from string to Type. but I keep getting the errors.
Looking like this: Also tried ConstructUsing.

```
    CreateMap<string, Country>()
        .ConvertUsing(s => new Country { Name = s });

    CreateMap<string, ZIP>()
        .ConvertUsing(s => new ZIP { Code = s });

    CreateMap<string, Street>()
        .ConvertUsing(s => new Street { Name = s });
```

Do I need to create a map for Address too? If so, how should I do that because I don't know how it sees the object, and how I should create a map for it.

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

This is part of the DTO I am sending up the API endpoint to register a user,
This is the mapping used:

```
CreateMap<UserRegisterDTO, User>();
```

And this is how the DTO looks like:

```
using Kubex.Models;

namespace Kubex.DTO
{
    public class UserRegisterDTO
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is how the User class looks like:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Kubex.Models
{
    public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

        public int? AddressId { get; set; }
        public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<License> Licenses { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my service, I use this line to do the mapping:

```
var newUser = _mapper.Map<User>(dto);
```

Comment: How does your API endpoint request type look like?

Comment: @Giedrius I editted the post and added more information in regards to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, Address class used in UserRegisterDTO is the same as in User. Not saying that this is a directly an issue, but from architecture standpoint it is, as you're mixing your DTO with database model (I guess), DTO should reference only simple types or other DTO's.

Hence, I would rather have something like this:

```
public class UserRegisterDTO
{
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public AddressDTO Address { get; set; }
}

public class AddressDTO {
   public string HouseNumber { get;set; }
   public string AppartementBus { get;set; }
   public string Street { get;set; }
   public string ZIP { get;set; }
   public string Country { get;set; }
}
```

and may be then mapping from AddressDTO to Address:

```
   CreateMap<AddressDTO, Address>()
     .ForMember(d => d.Country, d => d.MapFrom(s => new Country { Name = s.Country }))
  // cut for brevity
```

But I still don't like this. As this mapping would create country instance with each request and depending on your setup it might even create new row in database. May be better for it would be to lookup country within existing ones?

You can pass list of country instances through mapping context and use in ResolveUsing, but I personally prefer not to have complex logic in AutoMapper mappings, as that scatters business logic in at least two places and complicates unit testing.

Automapper is great for doing simple things, but if you feel that it is pushed to its limits, it is better to do at least some parts of the mapping manually in my opinion.

Comment: How would you go about it looking up the country in the database? I kind of do this already as all addresses ought to be unique in the database to counter duplicates. This is just purely for transforming the json object in to that address object. But as it seems, there is no other way than creating instances of those classes. Is it a big performance hit?

Comment: From the fact, that Country class has Id field I'm guessing that you have separate table in database for them. Let me ask, what happens with Id field value in that new Country instance?

Comment: The Id value is not used here. Only if you were to look it up by id specifically